# Django update an instance using another instance

Tags: django

For instance, I have instance a1 and a2.

I'd like to update a1 to be same as a2. (except id field)

Following is what I came up with, not sure if it will work though and if there's a better way.

```
a2_data = model_to_dict(a2, exclude=['id'])

A.objcects.filter(id=a1.id).update(**a2_data)
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution you suggested works:

```
from django.forms.models import model_to_dict
a2_data = model_to_dict(a2, exclude=['id'])
A.objects.filter(id=a1.id).update(**a2_data)
```

If you want to avoid the update statement, you could instead do something like:

```
for key, value in a2_data.items():
    setattr(a1, key, value)
a1.save()
```

However, this method won't work if any of your fields are ForeignKeys, whereas the first method does handle them properly.

Comment: actually update method doesn't work. because django insists getting actual object for foreign key fields, unless you append `_id` to the field name.

Answer (score 0):

There is no thing like 'instance a1 the same as a2'. They can't be the same, at least they must have different IDs.

So it's impossible to do such updates in query. You have to filter the records which should be updated, to iterate over them and to do the changes you need.

Comment: @eugene so I believe it's now obvious for you that you can't do this with ```.update()```.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it will 100% work, but I believe it's worth trying:

```
a2 = A.objects.get(pk=a2_pk)
a1 = A.objects.get(pk=a1_pk)
a2.pk = a1.pk
a2.save()  # maybe force_update=True should be set here too
```